# Big SVG image seamless infinite pan

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have an svg image. It takes the entire screen of my html page. What I am trying to achieve is make the entire map pan infinitely and seamlessly. I am not sure I am explaining it clearly. When I move the map to the right, for example, the right part of the map will pop on the left side of the screen. Same with the vertical panning. Is there some script for that? Please look at the `jsfiddle` I created. Also, what is the best way to position such a big image? I want US to be in the center of the screen. Is it doable? Thanks guys. I hope someone will understand me here. Hehe.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y75jw3w9/

Comment: Do it the way [this](https://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/puzzledrag.html) works I guess. I.e view source. You need something more specific to make a good question here.

Comment: I don't think there's an obvious way. You could try positioning 4 of them together and transform the ones out of view as needed so they come into view, with javascript. No idea if it would look any good though :)